# Remote to Laptop That is Tethered to Cell, Anyone?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, silverlight-4.0, cloud, remote-desktop

We are in need of a solution that will allow us to access a laptop that is tethered to a cell phone via the Internet.

Most VNC type solution will not allow this due to the fact that the cell phone acts like a router and there is no IP address we can access and the cell phone does not allow port forwarding.

Is anyone aware of a remote desktop application where on the client side can be activated via a web browser and then via the web browser control the remote machine.  Also we need to be able to complete brand the web side as we want to integrate the solution into our custom site.

If anyone has any direction to help us go in it would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN (virtual private network) configuration could resolve this.

Laptop TCP connection to VPN host via tether connection.  VPN assigns an IP address to the virtual network adapter (provided by the VPN client) in the laptop .  Any machine on the VPN (or bridged to the VPN network) can access any other machine on the VPN.  There will be no port blocking because the network connection is carried through a tunnel.

Configuration of the VPN will be somewhat intensive.  An minimal configuration would be to hardcode the VPN IP addresses at the host and all clients.  Then clients would be able to reach each other by IP.  This would allow VNC to work properly and in theory other connections such as FTP or Windows networking (although slowly depending on link speed).

I believe there is a Microsoft solution for VPN.  If I recall correctly the VPN client is built-in to Windows XP.  I never used their solution, I assume server-side is built-in to Windows 2003 and later.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545442.aspx

edit: The VPN server itself would need to be on a static IP (maybe dynamic DNS service if dynamic IP) and reachable from the Internet either directly or via port forwarding.  I don't know if there are service offerings providing VPN.  Depending on needs and budget the solutions are widely varied.

Answer (score 1):

Your web application can create and serve up .rdp files on the fly that point to the laptop in question.  There's an interesting writeup here:

http://www.perthstreetbikes.com/forum/f40/nerdy-tips-starting-vnc-rdp-hyperlink-125321/

The web application would need to know the current IP address of each laptop (presumably they would be traveling / mobile).  To accomplish that, you could write and install a simple check-in service on each laptop that calls home with the laptop name and current IP whenever the IP changes.

Note though that some remote locations (e.g. hotels) may block RDP ports.

Comment: That is one of the issues we face, the laptop will be tethered to the cell and the cell acts like a router.  This is way we need to go through a known server to communicate via the server.  3 tier architecture.  Thank you for your help though and do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you maintain a database with LAPTOP_NAME, CURRENT_IP_ADDRESS and have the laptop post to a web service to update that database every time it gets a new IP, all you really need is a simple website on top of that database to list the laptops and their current IP address, possibly creating a .RDP file to make it more user friendly.  Not sure why you think that won't work?

Comment: The reason is that the laptop cannot be accessed directly via IP, hence the need to go through a server like Teamviewer for example.  Once the cell is tethered to the laptop, the cell acts like a router but does not allow port forwarding, so accessing the phone via IP from the user website wont work as the laptop will be crossing different networks, etc...  This is why normal VNC style of software will not word unfortunately in this situation.  Teamviewr we cannot embed into the website and brand with out look and feel, that is why we need another solution that we can SSO and brand.

Comment: How is some additional server going to be able to connect to the laptop?  I guess I don't see what you're getting at.  If no ports can be forwarded through the NAT layer, nothing can send commands to the laptop...

Comment: Have you looked at teamviewer? It is a cloud based solution. The laptop and the client connect to the could server, to a known IP that both can access. Through that server the two machines can interact. When you tether to a laptop via a iPhone, you cannot do port forwarding, therefore the client cannot get to the laptop unless you go through a known server to communicate that in web accessible. Any other ideas?